# Nginx fails to start after boot, but works fine with a manual command

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, systemctl

I've recently got an Ubuntu 18 server and I'm a little confused to say the least.

First: If I run `sudo service nginx start` or `sudo systemctl start nginx`, everything appears to work. My site is  loading, and both `sudo service nginx status` and `sudo systemctl status nginx` return an all clear message.

Now the issue: When I reboot my server, `nginx` isn't automatically being started as the website is not being loaded. I tried `sudo systemmctl enable nginx` and tried another reboot. Again, `nginx` is not running as the website isn't loading.

In fact, if I reboot my server `sudo reboot` and then `sudo service nginx status` or `sudo systemctl status nginx` I get an error message. Despite the error message, I can run `sudo service nginx start` or `sudo systemctl start nginx` and it'll all go back to working.

The error message I get is the following:

```
(venv) user@server:/data/project$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-02-26 17:50:18 CET; 1min 6s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 830 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 26 17:50:18 md3.tudelft.nl systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 26 17:50:18 md3.tudelft.nl nginx[830]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/data/project/uwsgi_params" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/paintingViewer.conf
Feb 26 17:50:18 md3.tudelft.nl nginx[830]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Feb 26 17:50:18 md3.tudelft.nl systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 26 17:50:18 md3.tudelft.nl systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 26 17:50:18 md3.tudelft.nl systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Well, that seems pretty simple: it can't find the uwsgi_params file. THe uwsgi_params file does exist though, and it is in the right location.

My `nginx` .conf file:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
     server unix:///data/project/paintingViewer.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket -> works if we use Djano's build in webserver.
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name server;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /data/project/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /data/project/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /data/project/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

and the `/data/project/uwsgi_params` file is:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Now, there's a few things I don't understand:

1) How is it possible that `nginx` works if I run the `start` command, but that `nginx` doesn't work on boot?

2) How can the `status` read that `nginx` can not find the `uwsgi` file, while it works on a `start`?

3) How can I get `nginx` to run properly on a reboot?

Comment: Is `/data` some external filesystem or other mount?

Comment: @Lenniey Oh, wow. Yes,it is. Is it trying to run `nginx` before `/data` is being mounted?

Comment: Could be, what kind of mount is it? How is it mounted? Using sytemd or manually via script or...?

Comment: @Lenniey I honestly don't know, and I don't know how to check. IT delivers them mounted like that. I'll contact them for the specifics ASAP but that'll take a day at least.

Comment: You could try `systemctl edit nginx.service` and add `[Unit] 
RequiresMountsFor=/data`.

Comment: @Lenniey Doing it without `sudo` tells `Failed to create directories for "/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf": Permission denied`. Running with `sudo` returns an empty file. Is that correct, or should there be a file here?

Comment: You're changing a systemd service, so sudo / root is necessary. The empty file is correct, as aoyu don't have any options atm. There should be a newline after `[Unit]`...is there any way to add a newline in a comment?

Comment: @Lenniey That did it! Thanks a lot, you've been super helpful. If you create and answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90269/discussion-between-lenniey-and-mitchell-van-zuylen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nginx can't find the file because the mount / external filesystem is not ready at startup after boot. To tell nginx to wait for the mount, use `systemctl edit nginx.service` and add the following lines:

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=<mountpoint>
```

or in you specific case:

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/data
```

nginx will now always wait for `/data` to be ready before starting.